# How to determine which tables are used by ASP.NET web solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, asp.net-mvc-3

Problem is a bit complex(or not) so I don't know exactly how to ask this question.

My project is hybrid of MVC and WebForms approach. It uses 3rd part software and it is packed with one quite big solution with a lot of little sub-systems. Whole project uses two databases A and B.

I wanna stop using both databases and merge it to single one - lets say it will be A. To achieve this I have to create some deploy script to migrate B tables into A. I am not only sure which tables I really want.

Main problem is I am not able to determine which tables are currently used (because some of them for sure are not - this is really messy). Additionally some table names are same in A and B. Is there any automated way to do this? This project is quite big and we hadn't been supplied with documentation. Manual way for identifying this stuff would be quite horrible.

Any ideas for speed up would be appreciated.

Best Regards.

Comment: @Jethro: I am wondering if sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats could help me a bit. Because currently I have got some staging environment which has been accessed by testing crew last month regularly. It could be better to analyse it in this case instead of Sql Profiler logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Profiler to seen what users are accessing your database.

If the two applications have different sql user login's you can quite easy see what queries are being run and which tables are being accessed.

[Sql Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx)

Comment: Yeah it is a bit helpful but still it means I have to review whole application functionality click by click. Is there any way to view it at build process? I mean when solution is build is there tool to find out which models(and connected to them tables) are used by code itself.

Comment: @Piotr Masior, Don't think so. What data access layer are you using? Entity Framework?

Comment: No, it is not based on entity framework. It is mixed with Unity and provides some kind of entity framework functionality but written from scratch.